# Finding density of the random variable X + Y

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

let
$$f:R^2 \rightarrow [0, \infty)$$

$$f(x,y) = 6(x-y) \ for \ 0 \leq y \leq x \leq 1$$
$$f(x,y) = 0 \ otherwise$$

The solution I have use P(X+Y < Z) then differentiates it .
However, the limit of integration in getting P(X+Y < Z) is split and I don't understand why.

$$P(X+Y \leq Z) = \int_0^{z/2} \int_0^x 6(x-y)\;\mathrm{d}y \mathrm{d}x+ \int_{z/2}^{z\Lambda1} \int_0^{z-x} 6(x-y)\;\mathrm{d}y \mathrm{d}x$$

The limit of integration:;

$$ y \in [0, x] \ and \ x \in [0, z/2] \tag1 $$
$$ y \in [0, z-x] \ later \ changed \ to \ y \in [2x - z, x] \ while \ x \in [z/2, z\Lambda1] \tag2 $$

So why it split like this? (I also not sure  how y changes its limit of integration in (2))

Comment: What is $Z$? A r.v. or a constant?

Comment: @geetha290krm a r.v

Comment: @geetha290krm it seems Z should be a constant

Answer (score 0):

There should not be a random variable $Z$. It should be a constant. Fix $0<z<2$. The joint pdf is supported on a triangle $S$ with vertices $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$, and $(1,1)$. The hypotenuse has a slope of $+1$. For a specific $z$, you must integrate over the region $\{(x,y):x+y\leqslant z\}$, which is the region beneath the line $y=z-x$. This region is a triangle $T$ with vertices $(0,0)$, $(0,z)$, and $(z,0)$. The slope of this hypotenuse is $-1$. So we want to integrate over the region $S\cap T$. Between $x=0$ and $x=z/2$, the region is bounded below by $y=0$ and above by $y=x$, which gives the first integral. From $x=z/2$ to $x=z\wedge 1$, the region is bounded below by $y=0$ and above by $y=z-x$. This gives the second integral.